While connecting to a remote machine with New-PSSession command -OpenTimeout option not working
I am trying to implement a script, which connects to a remote windows machine via winRM. For that, I am using New-PSSession command. But, there are some machines for which this command takes more than 10 mins to connect and I want to fail such connection with a timeout.
$sessOption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck
$sessOption.OpenTimeout = (New-Timespan -Seconds 20)
$sess = New-PSSession -computername $machineIP -Port $port -Credential $cred -Authentication negotiate -UseSSL -SessionOption $sessOption

But this -OpenTimeout flag does not seem to be working. It was asked here as well: Why is the OpenTimeout option not being applied to New-PSSession? but not answers

Do not get the open connection timeout confused with the data transfer timeout.  There is no option in PS for max time to send data.  Only an idle timeout.

@jdweng
I understand. Is there any option to set a connection time out for the New-PSSession command.

I do not see any with new-PSSession.  You co8ld create your own timer in PS.  Read following paragraph : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-pssessionconfiguration?view=powershell-7.4#description

Other OPs had same issue : https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5434
